# How can I auto-pause the audio player in my app when another app starts to play audio?

Tags: android

My app plays an audio file. I want my app to pause the audio playing if another apps starts to play audio. I don't want the two audio sounds mess up each other. My app will resume the audio playing after the other app finishes playing its audio. How can I make it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your application is running ie. while app is running in foreground (users is looking at your screen) or if your running a "service" which is currently in the background and you wish music to continue playing (songza, slacker radio etc.) how you handle these things will be different. Android uses internal system states to determine which apps should be out-putting audio to the speaker. All this is handled by the audio manager requestAudioFocus() releaseAudioFocus() will be the system calls you will want to look at the most. For a more detailed explanation see android developer api where you this is explained and documented quite well http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html